# html <img> not displaying

Tags: java, html

I'm using eclipse for website and i would like to know why

```
<img alt=\"Chocolattt\" scr=\"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/w_1quQbOqpI/maxresdefault.jpg\">
```

don't want to display image and i tried

```
<img alt=\"Chocolattt\" scr=\"chocolat.jpg\">
```

and it's dosen't work too ;-;
In the console, this should appear but it's dosen't:

```
GET /chocolat.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

The problem is java or html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO Quix.

You need to use `src` not `scr`.